# Does the low gravity on Moon eliminate the need for a launch pad/flame trench for a reusable rocket launch?

Tags: spacex, launch, the-moon, falcon-heavy, launchpad

I'm new to rocket science and I learned how the rockets do not reach full thrust immediately and isn't really stable for the initial couple of seconds - hence the need for "launch clamps" and a vertical pad. Considering this and the fact that Falcon Heavy is expected to deliver payloads for the upcoming Artemis missions, can we - hypothetically - launch a "fully-reusable" version of Falcon Heavy into LLO from the lunar surface without a launch pad and a flame trench, taking advantage of low gravity? Is the initial part of lift-off still going to be a problem in terms of rocket stability?

Comment: While it may not be necessary for the rocket, it would be quite important for any ground infrastructure for similar reason as mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23429/lunar-excavation-by-blasting-would-there-be-unique-challenges-difficulties-or/23434#23434)

Comment: The Apollo 12 lunar module landed 180m from the Surveyor 3 probe, with results: "During the 31 months that Surveyor 3 was on the Moon, the white surface of the camera was discolored; in the final stages of LM landing, lunar dust was accelerated by the LM exhaust. This dust literally sandblasted the Surveyor spacecraft, removing much of the discoloration, except in areas that were shielded. The sharpness of the shadows created by the shielding indicates that the path of the lunar dust was only slightly curved by lunar gravity, indicating the lunar dust was traveling in excess of 100m/sec."